# Como pegar o valor de uma option e, ao clicar nela, fazê-la criar um input de texto?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <select class="select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <ul>
            <li>Nº do Protócolo?</li>
        </ul>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>

    </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bem simples a pergunta mas a contextualização poderia melhorar, esclarecendo  quando selecionar a próxima opção criara um novo input cada opção escolhida resultara nisso, criara input **a** , **b** ... se isso é o centro da pergunta.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Se for para criar uma lista de inputs com o seu atributo "name" de acordo com o selecionado nas options, tente algo como:

```
<body>
  <select class="select" id="select" onChange="inputSelecionado()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
  </select>
  <div id="container_inputs"></div>
</body>
<style>
  #container_inputs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column
  }

</style>
```

Onde a função inputSelecionado() sempre será executada quando você mudar a opção.

```
function inputSelecionado() {
  var select = document.getElementById('select');
  var container_inputs = document.getElementById('container_inputs');

  if (select.value !== '') {
    container_inputs.innerHTML += "<input placeholder='Input Selecionado " + select.value + "' name='" + select.value + "'/>";
  }
}
```

Na função, ela pegara os elementos pelo id, verificar se o valor selecionado é diferente
de vazio e por fim adicionar o input na div #container_inputs através do innerHTML

Caso seja para ter só um input de acordo com o selecionado, tente algo como:

```
function inputSelecionado() {
  var select = document.getElementById('select');
  var container_inputs = document.getElementById('container_inputs');

  if (select.value !== '') {
    container_inputs.innerHTML = "<input placeholder='Input Selecionado " + select.value + "' name='" + select.value + "'/>";
  }
}
```

Onde ao invés de adicionar um elemento na div através do operador "+=", o conteúdo da div será somente o que lhe será atribuído.